# Avoiding picking up future dates in Calendar Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I have a Calendar, so I can get dates by:

```
Calendar cld = new Calendar();
cld.getCurrentDate();
```

also:

```
cld.getDate();
```

So I have the current date and the date which I chose in the Calendar. What I'm trying to do is like:

```
Date currentdate = cld.getCurrentDate();
Date chosendate = cld.getDate();
long math = Math.abs(currentdate.getTime() - chosendate.getTime());
long result = math / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

 if(result < 0)Dialog.show("Invalid Date", "Please select a valid date.", "OK", null);
```

Not sure if my method is correct, actually I wanna a method to avoid picking up future dates from the Calendar, how to do that in Codename One?

**EDITED:**

```
Calendar cld = new Calendar() {
   protected void updateButtonDayDate(Component dayButton, int year, int currentMonth, int day) {
       super.updateButtonDayDate(dayButton, year, currentMonth, currentDay);
       dayButton.setEnabled(isDateValid(year, currentMonth, day));
   }
};
```

My isDateValid() method:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DateValidator {

    public boolean isDateValid(int year, int currentMonth, int day) {

        if(Calendar.MONTH < currentMonth-1)return false;
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

I had to create a new class since I was already using the Calendar from Codename One in my other Class, and it doesn't provide `Calendar.MONTH`. I can't pick up future months, but it still allow me to pick up future days and future years. I wish I could use the method Date.after() from the original java.util.Date, the Date from Codename One doesn't have the method after() which is making it difficult for me to find out a way. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can derive `Calendar` and provide that logic yourself:

```
Calendar cld = new Calendar() {
   protected void updateButtonDayDate(Component dayButton, int year, int currentMonth, int day) {
       super.updateButtonDayDate(dayButton, year, currentMonth, currentDay);
       dayButton.setEnabled(isDateValid(year, currentMonth, day));
   }
};
```

The `isDateValid()` can be anything in this case only past dates:

```
private boolean isDateValid(int year, int currentMonth, int day) {
   java.util.Calendar cld = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
   cld.set(java.util.Calendar.YEAR, year);
   cld.set(java.util.Calendar.MONTH, currentMonth);
   cld.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
   return cld.getTime().getTime() < System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shai, that `isDateValid()` method you mentioned, I'm having a hard time to figure out the logic, look at my code I updated it, sorry for my lack of experience.

Comment: Edited my answer